# how can i modify a text file by perl

Tags: perl

I want to make 'find/change' function.

1. open original file.
2. change some words through using s/ / / or tr/ / / but it's not working, i think.

   ```
   open(TXT, ">>text.txt");
   my $str = <TXT>;
   $str =~ s/'a'/'b'/;
   print TXT $str;
   ```

Comment: Another example where `use strict` and `use warnings` would have given some useful pointers to the solution.

Comment: Your solution does not have a loop.  It will only operate on one line.  Also, as pointed out below, you're opening the file for output, not input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at this example:

```
 ...
open RH, "text.txt" or die $!;
chomp(my @lines = <RH>);
close RH;

open WH, ">text.txt" or die $!;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
  $line =~ s/'a'/'b'/;
  print WH "$line\n";
}
close WH;
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program opens a file for *append*, so you won't be able to read from it and the line `my $str = <TXT>` will set `$str` to `undef`.

You can write this as a one-line console command, using

```
perl -i.backup -pe"s/'a'/'b'/g" myfile
```

which substitutes the string `'a'` (including the quotes) with the string `'b'` throughout the file, and saves a backup to `myfile.backup`

Or you can write a program like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile' or die qq{Unable to open input file: $!};

while (<$fh>) {
  s/'a'/'b'/g;
  print $_;
}
```

which leaves the input file intact and sends the modified data to STDOUT, so it can be redirected to a new file with the command

```
perl modify.pl myfile > myfile.new
```